# When does Play load application.conf?

Tags: scala, playframework, config

Is `application.conf` already loaded when the code in `Global.scala` is executed? I'm asking because I've tried to read some configuration items from `Global.scala` and I always get `None`. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java it's available `beforeStart(Application app)` already

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
     public void beforeStart(Application app) {
        String secret = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.secret");
        play.Logger.debug("Before start secret is: " + secret);
        super.beforeStart(app);
    }   
}
```

As it's required to i.e. configuring DB connection, most probably [Scala works the same way](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/scala/index.html#play.filters.csrf.Global%24) (can't check)

Comment: In my case the right place is onLoadConfig... but your answer was really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Add the proper solution then for other guys :)

Comment: OK, see here below my full answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here below is how to read the configuration just after it has been loaded but before the application actually starts:

```
import play.api.{Configuration, Mode}
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import java.io.File
import utils.apidocs.InfoHelper

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onLoadConfig(
    config: Configuration,
    path: File, classloader:
    ClassLoader,
    mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {

    InfoHelper.loadApiInfo(config)
    config
  }
}
```

And here below, just for your info, is the source of `InfoHelper.loadApiInfo` – it just loads API info for **Swagger UI**:

```
package utils.apidocs

import play.api.Configuration
import com.wordnik.swagger.config._
import com.wordnik.swagger.model._

object InfoHelper {

  def loadApiInfo(config: Configuration) = {
    config.getString("application.name").map { appName =>
    config.getString("application.domain").map { appDomain =>
    config.getString("application.emails.apiteam").map { contact =>
      val apiInfo = ApiInfo(
        title = s"$appName API",
        description = s"""
          Fantastic application that makes you smile.  You can find our
          more about $appName at <a href="//$appDomain">$appDomain</a>.
        """,
        termsOfServiceUrl = s"//$appDomain/terms",
        contact = contact,
        license = s"$appName Subscription and Services Agreement",
        licenseUrl = s"//$appDomain/license"
      )

      ConfigFactory.config.info = Some(apiInfo)
    }}}
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.